# Most effective way to connect to an Ubuntu vps from Windows?

Tags: 10.04, vnc, rdp, freenx

I have a vps with ubuntu 10.04 x64, I used FreeNX, and it's lacking.

Is there an application with better compression algorithm(s)?

Answer (score 0):

10.04 has remote desktop built in if you go to "System->Preferences->Remote Desktop" you should be able to enable it.

Comment: What client do I need for it?

Comment: http://terminals.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

FreeNX I believe is better than both rdesktop and vnc and is supposed to work on even 
modem connections.

Maybe you can lower your resolution / color depth?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only doing server-type tasks (no GUIs), then ssh (Secure Shell) is the best and fastest way to connect to it. It's text-only, which means that you don't waste bandwidth on imagery.  From windows, PuTTY is a great free ssh client:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html